# Is there a possible way to restrict processing of socket emits and make delay between them?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

For example: to prevent user spam in chat room, is there a socket.io server side solution that could prevent user from emitting event if 3 seconds for example haven't passed yet?

Answer (score 0):

On a rough look, it seems you'd need to implement any filtering like this client-side, the docs don't seem to show any hooks for message filtering.  You could have your clients send to a different channel than the one they listen to, then setup a relay on the server that listens to one channel, filters then emits to another...